# How to create custom commands in Grails 3?

Tags: grails, grails-3.0

I need to create custom command in Grails 3 which I can then execute from command line as we can generate default commands such as run-app. I am not sure whether to create script or anything else to achieve this.

Comment: You mean shell/ bash script?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions seem to work

```
[0] % grails create-app script-test
| Application created at /Users/kirk/tmp/script-test

[0] % cd script-test

[0] % grails create-script my-script

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

| Rendered template Script.groovy to destination src/main/scripts/my-script.groovy

[0] % cat src/main/scripts/my-script.groovy
description "Example description", "grails example-usage"

println "Example Script"%

[0] % grails my-script
Example Script

[0] % grails
| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails> my-script
Example Script
```

Tab completion works also.

However, if you create the script with an interactive shell running, that shell won't see the script until you restart the shell.

```
[0] % grails
| Enter a command name to run. Use TAB for completion:
grails> create-script wibble
| Rendered template Script.groovy to destination src/main/scripts/wibble.groovy
grails> wibble
| Error Command not found wibble
Did you mean: assemble or clean or gradle?
grails> % quit
[0] % grails wibble
Example Script
grails> wibble
Example Script
grails>
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation to the rescue! [Here](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.4/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html) is how to do what you are asking.

Comment: Okay Thanks. But If I execute the script name in Grails shell, it shows me 'No command found.'

Comment: You're telling me what you did, but you aren't `showing` anything. Edit your question and give line by line what you did to try this.